# Scala Retrieve aggregate pattern inside flat map

Tags: scala

I have this scenario when trying to aggregate the result of few methods .

What im trying to do is im getting a Future of an object that contain a list of objects .

Then im flat mapping the future  to a list of strings 
and then i would like to  iterate this list

Than invoke  couple of methods  if it possible in a async way and then merge the result to one object i have to wait that all method will finish 
 and send the result to a database.

This is where i stuck ....

**UPDATE**

I edit the method as suggested  in the comments  now i getting type mismatch error

```
expected List[postMd.PostMD]....
```

,

```
def getComplatePost(url: String): Unit = {
  val postMd = new PostMetaData
  val com = new Comments
  val post = new Post
  val fullPost = new CompletePost


  val postMdList: Future[List[postMd.PostMD]] = postMd.getPostMetaData(url, "396697410351933") // get the list of id
  postMdList.flatMap(x => {
    val fromid = x.map(_.fromID) //extract  the  Future to a list of string

   for {
    id <- fromid
    val c = com.getComments(id)
    val p = post.getPost(id)
  }yield (c,p)

  })
  }
```

thanks 
miki

Comment: Could you add type declarations to `c`, `p` and `k`? Probably a `for` - `yield` combination can perform what you want.

Comment: @GáborBakos  i added the type deceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a 'for - yield' this case. 'for' executes the yield operation after each of its statement completes.

This mainly hold as, **'for'** is a syntactic sugar which further gets mapped to nested flatMap or map or foreach ... depending on the operations being performed.

Below is a modified snippet from your code:

```
for {
  id <- fromid
  //invoke methods
  c = com.getComments(id)
  p = post.getPost(id) 
  k = post.getPostLikes(id)
} // merge results and send data to DB
```

Comment: I think you meant `for`-`yield`. `for` alone is just `foreach`.

Comment: Yeah. Edited the post for the same. Thanks :)

Comment: I can't merge the result back im getting a type mismatch
expected [List[postMd.PostMD]] how can i return a new type ?

Comment: Can you provide the full error. Also, what do you mean by return a new type?

Comment: Something that can hold the result of C and P 

      for {
        id <- fromid
        val c = com.getComments(id)
        val p = post.getPost(id)
      }yield  new SingePost(c,p)

Comment: I see the expected value, but what are you getting.